# Flutter: remove an element in the List<ObjectWidget> with index is correct but invalid in the List<Widget>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the list of an object and in the object have the widget.
The `List<Object>` can add or remove the object.
When I remove the object in this list, the value in this object is correct. but the widget in this object is incorrect.
Why? The widget in the Object should belong to this object. This should be correct. How to fix this?

example code:
Try to add a field 2 times and type the name of the first field with 'A' and 'B' for the second then remove the first field('A' should be removed). the rest of the field will show 'A'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: MyWidget())));
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Testpage();
  }
}

class Testpage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Testpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Testpage> createState() => _TestpageState();
}

class _TestpageState extends State<Testpage> {
  List<TestWidgetGroup> fieldList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('\nBuild\n');
    List<Widget> children = [];
    for (int index = 0; index < fieldList.length; index++) {
      print(
          '\nindex at $index, name = ${fieldList[index].object.name}, phone = ${fieldList[index].object.phone}'); // correct value
      children.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(children: [
          fieldList[index].nameField,
          fieldList[index].phoneField,
          Center(
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => setState(() => fieldList.removeAt(index)),
                  child: const Text('remove'))),
        ]),
      ));
    }
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          children: children +
              [
                Center(
                    child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () =>
                            setState(() => fieldList.add(TestWidgetGroup())),
                        child: const Text('add')))
              ],
        )));
  }
}

class TestWidgetGroup {
  TestObject object = TestObject();
  late Widget nameField =
      buildTextField((v) => object.name = v, 'name: ${object.name}');
  late Widget phoneField =
      buildTextField((v) => object.phone = v, 'phone: ${object.phone}');
}

class TestObject {
  String? name;
  String? phone;
}

Widget buildTextField(Function(String?) onChanged, String text) {
  print(text);
  return TextFormField(onChanged: onChanged);
}
```

Comment: all I can say is that you are letting object references take care of your widget tree, that's a incredible source of untraceable bugs. Instead make it declarative and reactive, a nice start is to avoid changing object properties directly, instead create new instances of it https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/declarative

Comment: Thank you. I try to create the object of this widget. For example, the `userObject` has the parameter name that is the object too so when I want the widget of the first name I just use `UserObject.name.firstName` or `CustomerObject.name.firstName`. But I think this is too difficult for this or I should code in a basic way.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can do it by using the `Key`. Add `List<Key> fieldKeyList = [];` with a unique string.
code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart' as mongo;

class Testpage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Testpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Testpage> createState() => _TestpageState();
}

class _TestpageState extends State<Testpage> {
  List<TestWidgetGroup> fieldList = [];
  List<Key> fieldKeyList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('\nBuild\n');
    List<Widget> children = [];
    for (int index = 0; index < fieldList.length; index++) {
      print('\nindex at $index, name = ${fieldList[index].object.name}, phone = ${fieldList[index].object.phone}'); // correct value
      children.add(Padding(
        key: fieldKeyList[index],
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(children: [
          fieldList[index].nameField,
          fieldList[index].phoneField,
          Center(
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    fieldKeyList.removeAt(index);
                    setState(() => fieldList.removeAt(index));
                  },
                  child: const Text('remove'))),
        ]),
      ));
    }
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          children: children +
              [
                Center(
                    child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          fieldKeyList.add(Key(mongo.ObjectId().$oid));
                          setState(() => fieldList.add(TestWidgetGroup()));
                        },
                        child: const Text('add')))
              ],
        )));
  }
}

class TestWidgetGroup {
  TestObject object = TestObject();
  late Widget nameField = buildTextField((v) => object.name = v, 'name: ${object.name}');
  late Widget phoneField = buildTextField((v) => object.phone = v, 'phone: ${object.phone}');
}

class TestObject {
  String? name;
  String? phone;
}

Widget buildTextField(Function(String?) onChanged, String text) {
  print(text);
  return TextFormField(onChanged: onChanged);
}
```

However, why does the flutter make the controller remove always remove the last of the list instead of the target index?